# informatica generate session with default values

Tags: informatica, informatica-powerexchange

Is it possible to set a default session parameter in Informatica?
I want to set the target, the source, default database and set the target schema on the prefix and default schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared parameter file for all the workflows and provide default values for your parameters in the parameter file in the below format:

```
[Global]
$DBConnection=DB_NAME
$Source=SRC_NAME
$Target=TGT_NAME
$PMMergeSessParamFile=TRUE
```

Then you can override these values for any specific workflow that you need.